# How to create a custom equality function with reselect and Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, reselect

A standard reselect selector invalidates its memoized value and recomputes it if the input selectors fail a strict equality check:

```js
export const selectEmailsFromComments = createSelector(
  selectComments, // returns an array of comments
  comments => commentsToEmails(comments)
)
```

Since the comments are an array and not a primitive value, and redux reducers tend to create a new piece of state to avoid side effects, the above seems to never actually memoize because the comments array returned by `selectComments` will always have a different reference.

To resolve this, one can create a [custom selector creator](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#customize-equalitycheck-for-defaultmemoize), e.g. to introduce shallow equality checks:

```js
const createShallowEqualSelector = createSelectorCreator(
  defaultMemoize,
  shallowEqual
)

export const selectEmailsFromComments = createShallowEqualSelector(
  selectComments, // returns an array of comments
  comments => commentsToEmails(comments)
)
```

This works if the comments indeed are simple objects and we want to recompute the emails whenever any of the comments' props changed.

But what if we only want to recompute the emails if e.g. the number of comments changed? How could we implement a custom equality check? I would expect the following to work:

```js
type ComparisonFunction<B extends object = {}> = (prev: B, next: B, index: number) => boolean

const createCustomEqualSelector = <B extends object = {}>(
  equalFn: ComparisonFunction<B>
) => createSelectorCreator<ComparisonFunction<B>>(defaultMemoize, equalFn)

const commentsEqualFn = (a: IComment[], b: IComment[], index: number) =>
  a.length === b.length

export const selectEmailsFromComments = createCustomEqualSelector(
  commentsEqualFn
)(
  selectComments, // returns an array of comments
  comments => commentsToEmails(comments)
)
```

However this returns the following Typescript error for defaultMemoize:

```
(alias) function defaultMemoize<F extends Function>(func: F, equalityCheck?: (<T>(a: T, b: T, index: number) => boolean) | undefined): F
import defaultMemoize
Argument of type '<F extends Function>(func: F, equalityCheck?: (<T>(a: T, b: T, index: number) => boolean) | undefined) => F' is not assignable to parameter of type '<F extends Function>(func: F, option1: ComparisonFunction<B>) => F'.
  Types of parameters 'equalityCheck' and 'option1' are incompatible.
    Type 'ComparisonFunction<B>' is not assignable to type '<T>(a: T, b: T, index: number) => boolean'.
      Types of parameters 'prev' and 'a' are incompatible.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'B'.ts(2345)
```

How would I resolve this type error for a custom reselect createSelector equality function?

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me but I'm not sure if it's the best way.

```
import {
  createSelectorCreator,
  defaultMemoize,
} from 'reselect';

type IComment = { id: number };
type State = { comments: IComment[] };
type CompareFn = <T>(a: T, b: T, index: number) => boolean;
const createCustomEqualSelector = (equalFn: CompareFn) =>
  createSelectorCreator(defaultMemoize, equalFn);
const selectComments = (state: State) => state.comments;
const commentsEqualFn: CompareFn = (a, b, index) =>
  //need to cast it or get an error:
  //  Property 'length' does not exist on type 'T'
  ((a as unknown) as IComment[]).length ===
  ((b as unknown) as IComment[]).length;

export const selectEmailsFromComments = createCustomEqualSelector(
  commentsEqualFn
)(
  selectComments, // returns an array of comments
  (comments) => {
    console.log('calculating comments:', comments);
    return comments;
  }
);
selectEmailsFromComments({ comments: [{ id: 1 }] })
//this will log previous value because array length didn't change
console.log('memoized', selectEmailsFromComments({ comments: [{ id: 2 }] }))
```

Comment: Hmm, what is the point of the `<T>` in the CompareFn if we never use the type generic?

Comment: It would be better if we could do something like `const commentsEqualFn: CompareFn<IComment[]> = (a, b) => a.length === b.length` but this gives me errors again

Comment: `what is the point of the <T> in the CompareFn if we never use the type generic` That is how it comes from reselect. `type comp<T> = (a:T,b:T,c:number)=>boolean` would be better than then `type comp = <T>(a:T,b:T,c:number)=>boolean` but that is not how it's defined in reselect. I don't know enough about typescript to have a valid opinion of this but you can create an issue or a pull request it that is indeed a better way.