# Unable to define type for generic compare function with typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I can't get this to work, not sure how to explain the type to typescript for the following code:

```
interface hasLength {
  length: number;
}
type CompareFn = <T> (a: T, b: T) => boolean
const compare = (compareFn: CompareFn, a: hasLength, b: hasLength) => 
  compareFn(a, b)
const compareFn: CompareFn = (a, b) => a.length === b.length//error here
const otherCompare: CompareFn = (a, b) => a === b
console.log(compare(compareFn, [1], [2]))
console.log(compare(compareFn, 'a', 'b'))
console.log(compare(otherCompare, [1], [2]))
```

The compare function gets 2 parameters of the same type or interface and is used in the function compare. The error is `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'T'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things:

1. `CompareFn` isn't generic, the `<T>` isn't quite in the right place.
2. Any specific `CompareFn` will need to specify the generic type constraint such that the generic type has any properties that it uses.

Here's a corrected version with comments calling out the changes/additions:

```
interface hasLength {
  length: number;
}

type CompareFn<T> = (a: T, b: T) => boolean
//            ^^^

const compare = (compareFn: CompareFn<hasLength>, a: hasLength, b: hasLength) => 
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
  compareFn(a, b)
const compareFn: CompareFn<hasLength> = (a, b) => a.length === b.length
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
const otherCompare: CompareFn<any> = (a, b) => a === b
//                           ^^^^^
console.log(compare(compareFn, [1], [2]))
console.log(compare(compareFn, 'a', 'b'))
console.log(compare(otherCompare, [1], [2]))
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=72&pln=11&pc=84#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBZwM4BkIgOZirIDeAsAFDLIA2uBqAXMiAK4C2ARtANwUC+FCmACeABxQBhAPZtRcKBABiIADwAVAHzIAvMgAUcJmoA0yDkYCUOrRylTacEBQD0zqu4-uAej8HkEUiAYYMgBsvIounphcgrKTNLhcaro2HSEGqaGaJg4+ISm5jlp+ahW2loubp41tXV1Po1NvpShMrFKIAaFFhQBQSExEfHIiR3KKql59FpRcD3WyHAAdLSlOtq6HKvpqFX1B57Nx32BwchShNBjEQntw6qOwrP682blWnAbW-uHf95NU5BewQVZSPDRe4KSFJTqmADaAEYALoIgBMyIsvX8ZxBYIhQ2hhLhyAA5HBSaZSRxSVigRg8dRwTCOnpLqhrlCIAiUejMRYgA)

---

Side note: By overwhelming convention, `hasLength` should be `HasLength`. Interface and class names start with an initial uppercase character (again, by convention).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried to type it according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62480158/1641941). The type there is `<T>(a: T, b: T, index: number)` and can't be changed. You did answer my question here though so I'll accept it.